# Add images to a database for q quiz app

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm developping and android quizz app and i have two problems.
First i cannot update the questions and second i want to store images in the database with the questions.This my database code
Is there someone who can help me?
Thanks

```
    package com.example.toureamidou.piste;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by TOURE Amidou on 24/02/2016.
 */
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Question";
    private static final String TABLE_QUEST = "quest";
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_QUES = "question";
    private static final String KEY_ANSWER = "answer";
    private static final String KEY_OPTA= "opta";
    private static final String KEY_OPTB= "optb";
    private static final String KEY_OPTC= "optc";
    private SQLiteDatabase dbase;
    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME,null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        dbase=db;
        String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_QUEST + " ( "
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_QUES
                + " TEXT, " + KEY_ANSWER+ " TEXT, "+KEY_OPTA +" TEXT, "
                +KEY_OPTB +" TEXT, "+KEY_OPTC+" TEXT)";
        db.execSQL(sql);
        addQuestions();

    }

    private void addQuestions() {
        Questions q1=new Questions("FFFFF","Tata", "Titi", "Toto", "Tata");
        this.addQuestion(q1);
        Questions q2=new Questions("Quel est le plus grand pays au monde", "Suisse", "Italie", "Chine", "Chine");
        this.addQuestion(q2);
        Questions q3=new Questions("Comment s'appele le président francais","Obama", "Hollande","Gorbatchev", "Hollande" );
        this.addQuestion(q3);
        Questions q4=new Questions("zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz", "ali", "dede", "home","dede");
        this.addQuestion(q4);
        Questions q5=new Questions("Quel est l'homme le plus riche au monde","Gates","Trump","Carlos Slim","Trump");
        this.addQuestion(q5);

    }

    private void addQuestion(Questions quest) {
        Log.d("addQuestions", quest.toString());
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_QUES, quest.getQUESTION());
        values.put(KEY_ANSWER, quest.getANSWER());
        values.put(KEY_OPTA, quest.getOPTA());
        values.put(KEY_OPTB, quest.getOPTB());
        values.put(KEY_OPTC, quest.getOPTC());
        dbase.insert(TABLE_QUEST, null, values);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_QUEST);
        onCreate(db);
    }
    public List<Questions> getAllQuestions() {
        List<Questions> quesList = new ArrayList<Questions>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_QUEST;
        dbase=this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = dbase.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Questions quest = new Questions();
                quest.setID(cursor.getInt(0));
                quest.setQUESTION(cursor.getString(1));
                quest.setANSWER(cursor.getString(2));
                quest.setOPTA(cursor.getString(3));
                quest.setOPTB(cursor.getString(4));
                quest.setOPTC(cursor.getString(5));
                quesList.add(quest);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        return quesList;
    }
    public int updateQuestions (Questions questions){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("questions",questions.getQUESTION());
        contentValues.put("answer",questions.getANSWER());
        contentValues.put("opta",questions.getOPTA());
        contentValues.put("optb",questions.getOPTB());
        contentValues.put("optc",questions.getOPTC());
        int i = db.update(TABLE_QUEST, contentValues, KEY_ID + " = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(questions.getID())});
        db.close();
        return i;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way You can also image load with asset folder

```
    //load image
try {
    // get input stream
    InputStream ims = getAssets().open("avatar.jpg");
    // load image as Drawable
    Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(ims, null);
    // set image to ImageView
    mImage.setImageDrawable(d);
}
catch(IOException ex) 
{
  ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in order for database records to "stick" you need to be in a Transaction.

```
 db.getWritableDatabase();
 db.beginTransaction();
 ...INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
 if (ok) {
    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
 }
 db.endTransaction();
 db.close();
```

images could be stored in a BLOB column.

Comment: Ahh thanks.In my code i tried to update using my update method but i didn't find.

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you say.

Comment: basically you MUST be in a transaction...and COMMIT it (using setTransactionSucessful() for the record to remain after you end the function, otherwise it is rolled back (removed!!)

Comment: Can you explain me how i can put it exactly in my code?Sorry i'm new on android so i don't understand all you say.Thanks

Comment: sure...where you have `db.update(...)` you need to surround that with the `db.beginTransaction();` and `db.endTransaction()` (of course with the `db.setTransactionSuccessful();`). then your record will be saved in the database (not rolled back). same with `db.insert(...);`

Comment: I have read on internet what you want to say me.But in my app i used a Linear layout which permits me to load the questions and answers.Would you want to say me that its adviced to use Fragments for this?

Answer (score 1):

Use this to get you image as String and save it

```
public String getStringImage() {

    if (bitmap != null) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
        String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
        return encodedImage;
    } else {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Ok Thank you i'll try it

Comment: @AmidouFlorianTouré You're welcome, say thanks in form upvote or accepting answer

Answer (score 0):

change image into byte{}

```
 Bitmap b=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.androidpics);
  ByteArrayOutputStream bos=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bos);
  img=bos.toByteArray();
```

insert image into database
 ................................................

```
 db=h.getWritableDatabase();
  btninsert.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {

     ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
            cv.put("image", img);
            db.insert("tableimage", null, cv);
            System.out.println("image insert successfully...............................");


   }
  }
```

);

Comment: Hi Gaurav can you help me in my code?Because i don't understand exactly.For example this is my class questions which i use to make the questiosn and answers to appear

Comment: i cannot post it sorry

Comment: When i put in the android studio said me the method getResources doesn't exists.Must i create it?